# RichEdit friendly name hyperlinks

Tags: c, winapi, hyperlink, richedit

I have created a regular link in a RichEdit control which can be clicked, I then capture the `WM_NOTIFY`/`EM_LINK` messages and handle the event accordingly. However, I wanted to change that to a "friendly" name hyperlink, something like HTML's `<a>` tag. It is surprisingly difficult to find information on this topic, however; the only reference was [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks.aspx) MSDN blogs article. While it does explain a bit, I'm still not sure how to implement such a hyperlink.

- Should I just use `WM_SETTEXT` like usual to set the formatted hyperlink text, and then handle it in the RichEdit's window procedure?
- They only mention RichEdit 5.0, 6.0 etc; I'm currently using RichEdit 2.0, is this functionality available only in later versions?
- If the answer to the previous question is yes, how do I actually load the proper DLLs? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page only tells me how to do it for the first four versions, what about the later ones?

Comment: Mapping EN_LINK from friendly to actual URL and doing something useful with it is entirely up to you.  Using 20 is fine.

Comment: Okay, but how to actually format the link so it's "friendly"? Using the formatting mentioned in that article doesn't work for me, it just shows the format used.

Comment: A bit unclear, I think you want to google "richedit cfe_link"

Comment: Just set the link text to your friendly string, then map to the appropriate URL when you get a click.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Well, I use URL autodetection and I doubt RichEdit will still mark regular string as URLs.